# Is jQuery 1.4 syntax the same as 1.3 and earlier?

Tags: jquery

We've written a lot of code in jQuery recently and id like to know if replacing the library with 1.4 will invalidate any of our current code or is the syntax identical?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the backwards-incompatible section of the JQuery 1.4 Release Notes.  It details the type of code which is expected to no longer function in 1.4

- http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards

Answer (score 1):

jQuery 1.4 is plain JavaScript too. So they are syntactically equivalent. But there are some [backwards-incompatible changes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards) you should be aware of.